# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that if $ F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ then $F(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, proof-explanation

I gave a two liner proof on a test for this as follows:

Proof: By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (First Form) $F'(x)=f(x)$, thus $F$ is differentiable. By an earlier Theorem, $F$ is continuous.

I looked back after submitting, and the earlier theorem states:

Theorem: Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in(a,b)$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Now I am pretty sure I messed this up because the bounds of the theorem are open, not closed. What should I have done to prove this correctly?

UPDATE: I received my exam back, and missed five points on this question (only 5 points that I missed) here is the feedback my professor gave:

Excellent!
The only problem is:
Problem 6: 5.  The First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus only works is f is continuous, not if f is merely integrable.  It is not, in general, true that F is differentiable for an integrable f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that whoever asked you this question expected this answer: since $f$ is Riemann integrable, then, in particular, it is bounded. Take $M>0$ such that $(\forall t\in[a,b]):|f(t)|<M$. If $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon M$. Then, if $x_0\in[a,b]$ and $x\in[a,b]$ is such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, the$$|F(x)-F(x_0)|=\left|\int_{x_0}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\leqslant M.|x-x_0|<\delta|x-x_0|<\varepsilon.$$

However, what you did is not silly. For *any* interval (with more than one point) $I$, every differentiable function from $I$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: Well that makes me feel a lot better!

Comment: Doesn't this also satisfy Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: @RealAnalysisNoob Yes, it does, since $|F(x)-F(x_0)|\leqslant M.|x-x_0|$.